# Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface | After Migrating form Oracle to Postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

Recently we migrate from Oracle to Postgres, After Migration in the same code segment we are having an issue, I tried to search for the solution and not yet resolved.

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-6] 2022-10-11 23:50:00,597 INFO DefaultLoadEventListener:160 - HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: com.<___>.crisp.model.hierarchy.HierarchyNode
[http-nio-8080-exec-6] 2022-10-11 23:50:00,624 ERROR LoggingMappingExceptionResolver:100 - Incident ID: 2022-10-11.23:50:00-19b90dad-4e4c-4001-ae62-065db5446a9d
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: com.<___>.<___>.model.hierarchy.HierarchyNode
at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:114)
at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:136)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:730)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4565)
```

I've checked the Database and everything looks good, Also posting the snippet that have the error.

```
public Set<String> getOeNodeCodes() {
    Set<String> oeNodeCodes = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for (OENode oeNode : getOENodes()) {
        oeNodeCodes.add(oeNode.getCode());
    }
    return oeNodeCodes;
}
```

The flow is not getting inside the function getOeNodeCodes(), Also at the starting of the class,

```
@Required
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private HierarchyNode rootNode;
```

The table that causes the issue,

Comment: it would appear you are trying to instantiate an abstract class or an interface, which is not possible, you'll need to provide (and use) a concrete subclass, or an implementation

Comment: It was working previously on Oracle db an now migrated to postgres sql and this issue happened.